# GoogleAPI spreadsheet Duplicated

Tags: python, excel, google-chrome, automation, google-drive-api

I would like to know what is going wrong?

I run this code in my server for backuping my data to the spreadsheet everyday morning.
The code usually failed on the second day. I tried to catch it and delete the duplicate page, but no idea what is going on. Error as below...

Failed {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid requests[0].addSheet: A sheet with the name "2020-11-12" already exists. Please enter another name.', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}

```
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
from oauth2client.service_account import  ServiceAccountCredentials

def goog_formatSlide(goog_spread, goog_slide):
        gc = goog_getpermission()
        sh = gc.open(goog_spread)
        ws = sh.worksheet(goog_slide)
    
        ws.update_acell("J4", "ABC")


def goog_uploadDataFrame(df, goog_spread): #goog_spread = googledrive_spreadsheet_name
    run = False 
    while not run: #while True
        try:
            A_pd = df
            gc = goog_getpermission() #authen the permission to access the drive
            sh = gc.open(goog_spread) #open drive_spreadsheet
            worksheet_name = goog_worksheet_name() #assign a name
            try:
                ws = sh.add_worksheet(title=str(worksheet_name), rows="500", cols="500") # add a new sheet 
                set_with_dataframe(ws, warrant_pd, row = 4, col =1 , include_index= True, include_column_header=True) # put the dataframe in the sheet
                goog_formatSlide(goog_spread, str(worksheet_name))
                run = True # assign format to the sheet

            except Exception as f: # if name is assigned before 
                print("Failed " + str(f))
                ws = sh.worksheet(str(worksheet_name)) # find out the duplicated sheet 
                sh.del_worksheet(ws) #delate the duplicated sheet 
                continue # do it again to make a new sheet with the same name 

        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed " + str(e))
            continue
```

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. You can't create a sheet with the same name as an existing one. Would you mind commenting the code dividing the steps you are trying to do, so we can understand better?

Comment: I added some comments, see is it help.
What I want to do is 
Open a sheet -> backup the dataframe 
If the sheet is exist
Delete the sheet and replace it with the new one

Comment: What python client or library are you using ? please link it in the question.

Comment: I added in the code

Comment: And this function `goog_worksheet_name()` ? Please see [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)